# Session isn't saving before header redirect

Tags: php, session, http-headers, sessionid

I am saving sessions in a database.
My code is as follows:

```
// session
$_SESSION['userID'] = $user->id;        
header('Location: /subdirectory/index.php');
```

Then at the top of index.php after the `session_start()`, I have var_dumped the $_SESSION global and the userID is not in there. I've looked through [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) and neither `session_write_close` or `session_regenerate_id(true)` worked for me.
Does anybody know a solution?

I have session_start() at the top of my file. When I var_dump the session global before the header redirect, I see the userID in there, but not in the other file, which is in a subdirectory of this script

Comment: Are you `session_starting()` where you do the redirect?

Comment: and are you sure that $user->id is set?

Comment: what is register_globals state?

Answer (score 14):

I found the solution (for me).
I've put an exit after the header.

```
$_SESSION['session'] = 'this is a session';
header('location: apage.php');
exit;
```

Comment: It is working only for the same directory. How to do this work for subdirectory? F.e.: from http:/domain.com to http:/domain.com/subdir/ ?

Answer (score 3):

If:
a) It appears in the session before redirect
b) other keys work

80% of the time the problem is register_globals, and use of a equally named variable $userID somewhere (the other 19% is just overwriting in places one doesn't expect, 1% is unable to write/lock session before redirect and stale data, in which case you *could* try session_write_close() before the redirect). It goes without saying register_globals should be off.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of this issue, but I haven't used sessions all that much.

With sessions you MUST do a few things and have a few setting setup:

- cookies enabled on client side
- session_start(), *before anything happens*
- make sure you don't destroy the session(unless they want to logout)
- The PHP session id must be the same (relates to cookies)

Another issue could be the $user->id is returning a reference to an object that doesn't exist on the next page. Most likely not, but make sure.

If I saw your code I could help you a lot more. But when debugging check the session key with session_id() and make sure it's the same. If you could try that then tell me I could keep helping.

I too would like to know how this ends up for when I get back into sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You should start the session before using the session array.

**PHP Code**,
session_start();
$_SESSION['userID'] = $user->id;
header('Location: /subdirectory/index.php');

Answer (score 0):

Have you got an session_start(); on the top?

Not tested but cant you do something like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userID'] = $user->id;
if( $_SESSION['userID'] == $user->id )
{  
    header('Location: /index.php');
}
```

I never have this Problem before, interesting

Comment: Yes, i do. When i var_dump the session global before the header redirect, its in there, just isnt when i go to a new file in a sub folder of the original script

Comment: @Matt funny, but its really interesting, because there should be set the Session, maybe any other code is deleting your session, are u sure nowhere else is a session_destroy(); ?

Comment: Strange, i changed $_SESSION['userID'] to $_SESSION['uid'] and it worked as expected. I dont know why the two capital letters make a difference. I tried it with userId aswell and that was fine too. 
Any ideas as to why it wouldnt accept userID? with two capitals, im baffled

Answer (score 0):

userID does not have any keyword status.

Only reason to me, is $_SESSION['userID'] is being overwritten or deleted somewhere.

Make sure you use session->start() in all the files you want to add/access the session.

One important thing ( which may not be applicable in your case ) is, if the session is being handled using cookie, cookie can be made to be accessible only under certain directory and subdirectories under that.
In your case anyhow, subdirectory will have access to the session.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both pages are the same php version
(php5, php4 sometimes have different session paths)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. I'm writting a customized MVC Website for school and, as everyone told, start_session() must be written in the very first lines of code.

My problem was THE LOCATION of "session_start()". It must be the first lines of your global controller, not the first lines of the view. $_SESSION was not accessible in controller's files because it was only initiated when the server render the view.

Then, I'm using session_write_close() after the header('location: xxx.php') call to keep session variables for the next request.

ex:

globalController.php :

```
//First line
session_start();
require_once('Model/Database.php');
require_once('Model/Shop/Client.php');
...
```

logonController.php:

```
...
//Users is validated and redirected.
$_SESSION['client'] = $client;
header('location: index.php');
session_write_close();
```

Hope it solved your problems.

Answer (score 0):

This was annoying as hell but I finally figured out a solution.

config.php i had:
include 'session.php';

At the top of session.php, I had:
session_start();

By moving session_start() to the top of the config.php file, viola...

Problem solved!

Comment: Its pretty good that you have solved the problem. I will just advise you to be little more clean in your solution so that it will help other readers too.

Answer (score 0):

Another option than killing your script forcefully with `exit` is to use `session_write_close` to force the changes to be written to the session store.

This should however not happen if your script is terminating correctly.

[As the documentation about `session_write_close` states:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

> End the current session and store session data.
>
> Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without
>   the need to call session_write_close(), but as session data is locked
>   to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session
>   at any time. When using framesets together with sessions you will
>   experience the frames loading one by one due to this locking. You can
>   reduce the time needed to load all the frames by ending the session as
>   soon as all changes to session variables are done.

In my case this only happened during debugging with `Xdebug`, when I triggered the same script multiple times and thus multiple process tried to manipulate the same session. Somehow the session could then no longer be unlocked.