# Can't figure out what's wrong with my PHP code

Tags: php, jquery

I have an admin page (admin.php) that I am setting up right now.

When the page is accessed initially, a login box comes up correctly where the user can hit a "Sign In" button.

When they hit the "Sign In" button, the login form gets submitted to a PHP page with this code (I don't have any authenticating going on right now - just starting to get this setup):

```
<?php
   session_start();  
   $_SESSION['login_success'] = true;

   header('Location:http://localhost/mbc/admin');
   exit();  

?>
```

Then, I'm expecting that the admin.php page will display the admin form but the page just shows up blank after the redirect.  Below is the applicable parts of the admin.php page.  Can any of you see what I'm doing wrong here such that the admin form is not displaying after the authentication is done?

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>Welcome Home!</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            /* Mask for background, by default is not display */
            #mask {
                display: none;
                background: #000; 
                position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; 
                z-index: 10;
                width: 100%; height: 100%;
                opacity: 0.8;
                z-index: 999;
            }

            /* You can customize to your needs  */
            .login-popup{
                display:none;
                background: #333;
                padding: 10px;  
                border: 2px solid #ddd;
                float: left;
                font-size: 1.2em;
                position: fixed;
                top: 50%; left: 50%;
                z-index: 99999;
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999; /* CSS3 */
                -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999; /* Firefox */
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999; /* Safari, Chrome */
                border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;
                -moz-border-radius: 3px; /* Firefox */
                -webkit-border-radius: 3px; /* Safari, Chrome */
            }

            img.btn_close { Position the close button
                float: right; 
                margin: -28px -28px 0 0;
            }

            fieldset { 
                border:none; 
            }

            form.signin .textbox label { 
                display:block; 
                padding-bottom:7px; 
            }

            form.signin .textbox span { 
                display:block;
            }

            form.signin p, form.signin span { 
                color:#999; 
                font-size:11px; 
                line-height:18px;
            } 

            form.signin .textbox input { 
                background:#666666; 
                border-bottom:1px solid #333;
                border-left:1px solid #000;
                border-right:1px solid #333;
                border-top:1px solid #000;
                color:#fff; 
                border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
                -moz-border-radius: 3px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
                font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                padding:6px 6px 4px;
                width:200px;
            }

            form.signin input:-moz-placeholder { color:#bbb; text-shadow:0 0 2px #000; }
            form.signin input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#bbb; text-shadow:0 0 2px #000;  }

            .button { 
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #f3f3f3, #dddddd);
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f3f3f3), to(#dddddd));
                background:  -o-linear-gradient(top, #f3f3f3, #dddddd);
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#f3f3f3', EndColorStr='#dddddd');
                border-color:#000; 
                border-width:1px;
                border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;
                -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
                color:#333;
                cursor:pointer;
                display:inline-block;
                padding:6px 6px 4px;
                margin-top:10px;
                font:12px; 
                width:214px;
            }
            .button:hover { background:#ddd; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body id="page1">
        <?php 
            session_start();
            if (isset($_SESSION['login_success'])) {
        ?>
        <!-- Some HTML content should show up here but it isn't... -->

        <?php } else { ?>

        <!-- Login Dialog -->
        <div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
            <a href="index.html">Cancel</a>
            <form method="post" class="signin" action="admin_process_login.php">
                <fieldset class="textbox">
                    <label class="username">
                        <span>Username</span>
                        <input id="username" name="username" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Username">
                    </label>
                    <label class="password">
                        <span>Password</span>
                        <input id="password" name="password" value="" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </label>
                    <button class="login" type="submit">Sign in</button>       
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                    //Getting the variable's value from a link 
                    var loginBox = document.getElementById('login-box');

                    //Fade in the Popup
                    $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

                    //Set the center alignment padding + border see css style
                    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
                    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

                    $(loginBox).css({ 
                        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
                        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
                        });

                    // Add the mask to body
                    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
                    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

                    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
                    $('button.login').live('click', function() { 
                            $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
                                $('#mask').remove();  
                                }); 
                            return false;
                            });
            });
        </script> 

        <?php } ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2012-02-25 16:54EST**
For some strange reason, this (and only this as far as I've tested so far) series of events makes the admin form come up correctly...
* Go to admin.php and click on "Sign In" button
* Go to "test" php page in browser (http://localhost/mbc/test)
Code for the test page:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Testing</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php
      session_start();
      if (isset($_SESSION['login_success'])) { ?>
      <H1>Login was a success</H1>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <H1>Login was a failure - next time it should work</H1>
      <?php
        $_SESSION['login_success'] = true;
      }
      ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

- Go to admin page (http://localhost/mbc/admin) and now the admin form comes up fine.

Comment: white page means that you need to check your error log now.

Comment: shouldn't it be `header('Location:http://localhost/mbc/admin.php');` or is your file actually missing the extension. If it's a folder the redirect should end with a slash, and then it will usually load the index file, if it exists.

Comment: @hakre - forgot to mention above that when I View Source on the white page, the stuff underneath the "<?php } else { ?>" is coming back - so it's as if the session isn't getting set correctly somehow...

Comment: @adeneo - the file does have the .php extension on it.  It comes up fine if I browse to it by just going to "http://localhost/mbc/admin".  I tried putting the ".php" extension on the header call but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Ярослав Рахматуллин - excuse me, I HAVE been doing research (quite a bit of it) and from what I've found MANY people have had issues with SESSION variables being not available on redirects which is what my issue appears to be.  I have flagged your comment as "rude" and I could flag is as "unconstructive" as well.  How about YOU do some research and check these links out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968752/php-session-isnt-saving-before-header-redirect & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415005/php-session-variables-not-carrying-over-to-my-logged-in-page-but-session-id-is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually in the jQuery button click code, specifically the "`return false`" portion:

```
// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
 $('button.login').live('click', function() { 
    $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
       $('#mask').remove();  
    }); 
    return false;
 });
```

When I removed that code, the "`$_SESSION['login_success'] = true;`" occurred fine and the admin form portion came back successfully.

Turns out "`return false`" has some nasty side effects and should be used carefully.  See
http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/ for more information on using "`return false`" correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have access to test it right now, but I think your problem is that it should be:

```
header('Location: http://localhost/mbc/admin');
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Both of the references show that a space after the ":" is needed before the URI.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You are simply expecting start_session() not to work and $_SESSION['login_success'] to be unset. I suggest you either use a php-framework or read a guide about sessions.

here, change like this and the form pops up:

```
  <?php
               //session_start(); // if you uncomment print_r will give you 1
               if (isset($_SESSION['login_success'])) {
                   echo '<pre>';
                   print_r($_SESSION['login_success']);
           ?>
           <!-- Some HTML content should show up here but it isn't... -->
                   empty statement</pre>
```

Comment: dude. read a guide.  http://www.php-learn-it.com/php_sessions.html: Note: "The session_start() function must appear BEFORE the <html> tag"

Comment: I've been reading MANY sites and have put session_start() at the top of all of my scripts.  There was no need to down-vote my question but there's an obvious need to down-vote your answer because you've given me information twice now that hasn't led me to a solution.  Please don't post anything else unless you're absolutely certain it will work.

Comment: BTW - as you can see in TEST.PHP, "session_start();" is NOT before the <html> and session is saving on that page so you're also providing erroneous information.

Comment: yeah.. I'm not going to start a discussion over this :) good luck, ok?