# Cookies not being set but rest of code executing?

Tags: php, cookies, error-handling

Well this is really confusing. I have two pages, A & B. Both use the following code:

```
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
     $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
     $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
     setcookie('user_id', $row['user_id'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));    // expires in 30 days
      setcookie('username', $row['username'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));  // expires in 30 days
      $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/main.php';
      header('Location: ' . $home_url);
```

A will execute the code after the setting of the headers (removed for your ease) and then set the headers;
B will execute the code after the setting of the headers and not set the headers.

I have checked out NUMEROUS answers, and there is no whitespace, the main.php file is set as normal, the A & B files look identical but with different content before the IF statement which irons out.

No error appears; the redirect (which should have headers set and react accordingly acts as if you were logged out (hence no headers active) on B, whereas on A it appears as intended.

The only difference between the two code blocks setting the cookies (both in a IF statement) is that the IF statement is different, according to code before it's appearance.

What (if any) kind of things should I look out for in terms of differences between the codes of A & B?

(PS: I also know that the headers aren't being set because the session is not started, by putting a IF $_SESSION ... towards the end of the code.

Comment: You need to use session_start(); see http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
setcookie('user_id', $row['user_id'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));    // expires in 30 days
setcookie('username', $row['username'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));  // expires in 30 days
$home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/main.php';
header('Location: ' . $home_url);
exit;
```

See

- [PHP: session isn't saving before header redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968752/php-session-isnt-saving-before-header-redirect)
- [How can I set a cookie and then redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612034/how-can-i-set-a-cookie-and-then-redirect-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer; moving session_start() aloud me to notice the code above was defining a if statement which ended immediately thus shutting down all the code inside of it..... although the fact that some got executed still eludes me....